# Are plugins for Android's native Web Browser version dependent?

Tags: android, browser-plugin, android-native-library

I've been trying the code Google provides with Android source code for a Browser Plugin, more specifically, following this README,

https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/qrd-gb-dsds-7225/repository/revisions/cc99b832a941dc8cbb86f1607d04eb87935ddbfd/entry/android/development/samples/BrowserPlugin/README

My question is, will I need to distribute a separate plugin for each platform(Froyo, Gingerbread, Honeycomb, etc)?. I'm planning to include native code within the plugin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the API of the native code is platform dependent, then yes. If the plugin API is platform dependent, then yes. Otherwise, no.