# Android browser plug-ins

Tags: android, google-chrome, webkit

How is the situation with the Android browser plug-ins?

- Can we develop the browser plug-in?
- Are there any limitations of what the plug-in can do?
- Can it be developed in C or Java only?

I have seen some people were already asking [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009946/are-plugins-for-androids-native-web-browser-version-dependent). Also [here](https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/qrd-gb-dsds-7225/repository/revisions/cc99b832a941dc8cbb86f1607d04eb87935ddbfd/entry/android/development/samples/BrowserPlugin/README) is written:

> plugin is intended to give plugin developers a point of reference to
>   see how an android browser plugin is created and how to use the available APIs.
>   A plugin is packaged like a standard apk and can be installed either via the 
>   market or adb.

But I did not found anything on the official developer.android.com pages as well as any plug-ins and on Android Market...

I am not 100% sure how it should work, but my expectation is that when browser loads an
HTML page that contains the new MIME Type in  tag, then Android brower should
and create instance of associated my browser plug-in.

In the Android web browser settings is an option to enable/disable plug-ins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome for Android it is not possible to load plugins or embeds.